# Cycles GPU Rendering support for GTX 1060

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have just built my new computer with a GPU bought to be specifically compatible with GPU rendering in Blender. I made sure it was on the list of CUDA cards and it has at least 2.0, (6.1 in fact).

Yet when I try to render I get the following error:

> CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute ability (6.1) not
>   found.

I have tried downloading and installing the CUDA toolkit, but it didn't help.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using? Support for the 10-series was added in 2.78, which was releaded only a few days ago. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78#Cycles_Renderer http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know, .77 as a matter of fact. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm hesitant to add this as an answer, as I can't test it myself, but please let the world know if it solved your your problem. :)